# how combine result from two tables and display in single column in sql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables `customer1` , `customer2` and `product` as shown below:

**Customer1 :**

```
c_id --- c_name
----------------
1    ---    anns

2    ---   skja

3    ---    kkjk
```

**customer2 :**

```
c_id --- c_name
----------------
11   ---  sjhja

12   ---  skkkkk

13   ---  aaasss
```

**product :**

```
p_id --- c_id ---  p_name
-------------------------
1    ---   1  ---   pen

2    ---   2  ---  card

3    ---   3  ---   cell

4    ---   11  ---  pot

5    ---   12  ---  ice

6    ---   13  ---  apple
```

I want to replace the value of `c_id` in `product` table with `c_name` from `customer1` and `customer2`

I am using below sql query :

```
SELECT c1.c_name or c2.c_name as customer_name, p.p_name from product p
left JOIN customer1 c1 on c1.c_id=p.c_id
left JOIN customer2 c2 on c2.c_id=p.c_id;
```

**getting result** :

```
c_name -----  p_name
---------------
null   -----  pen

null   -----  card 

null   -----  cell

null   -----  pot

null   -----  ice

null   -----  apple
```

**desired result :**

```
c_name -----  p_name
----------------------
anns    ----- pen

skja    ----- card 

kkjk    ----- cell

sjhja   ----- pot

skkkkk  ----- ice

aaasss  ----- apple
```

please help me out to get desired results.

Comment: Isnull(C1.name,c2.name)as[customer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this untested query:

```
SELECT ifnull (c1.c_name ,c2.c_name) as customer_name, p.p_name from product p
left JOIN customer1 c1 on c1.c_id=p.c_id
left JOIN customer2 c2 on c2.c_id=p.c_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT coalesce(c1.c_name,c2.c_name) as cus_name, p.p_name product_name 
from   product p
JOIN   customer1 c1 
on     c1.c_id=p.c_id
JOIN   customer2 c2 
on     c2.c_id=p.c_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    SELECT coalesce(c1.c_name,c2.c_name) as customer_name, p.p_name from product p
    left JOIN customer1 c1 on c1.c_id=p.c_id
    left JOIN customer2 c2 on c2.c_id=p.c_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help in your case

```
SELECT coalesce(k1.c_name,k2.c_name) as customer_name, j.p_name from product j
    left JOIN customer1 k1 on k1.c_id=j.c_id
    left JOIN customer2 k2 on k2.c_id=j.c_id;
```